# In hive,can we change location of managed/external table

Tags: hive, hiveql

In hive,can we change location of managed/external  table 
if yes how. After changing location will it behave like external table or internal table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to search this question but I didnt get a proper answer
yes we can change the location of managed table if we add location

```
CREATE TABLE weather (wban INT, date STRING, precip INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
LOCATION ‘ /hive/data/weather’;
```

After creation we can change location by the below command

```
ALTER (DATABASE|SCHEMA) database_name SET LOCATION hdfs_path
```

Even if we change the location the table will behave as managed table only

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's possible. And if you are looking for an external table location change, please use an alter script like below
ALTER TABLE users
SET LOCATION 'hdfs://hostname:port/source_folder_path'